# How to make ng-click work in a Angular DataTables column builder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

So I have this code:

**Controller:**

```
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('product_code').withTitle('Code'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('product_name').withTitle('Name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
            return ` <button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" ng-click="openViewProductModal(${data.product_id})">View</button>`;
        })
    ];

    $scope.openViewProductModal = function(id) {
       console.log(id)
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl as productControl" ng-init="loadProducts()">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="productControl.dtOptions" dt-columns="productControl.dtColumns" dt-instance="productControl.dtInstance" class="row-border hover"></table>
</div>
```

I can't even get the `console.log()` to work though everything is rendered perfectly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're dynamically adding a button with `ng-click`. The click won't activate on its own. You need to $compile stuff :  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below solution.Put a `createdRow` function after `vm.dtColumns` , you need to `compile row` for the `ng-click` event.

```
  vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('product_code').withTitle('Code'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('product_name').withTitle('Name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
            return ` <button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" ng-click="openViewProductModal(${data.product_id})">View</button>`;
        })
    ];

    function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    }

    $scope.openViewProductModal = function(id) {
       console.log(id)
    }
```

Comment: It worked. Now my problem is to how to pass the index of an item to the button.

Comment: @FewFlyBy ,I am not sure , but you may be find it in `meta`.

Comment: @chiragsatapara `ng-click="openViewProductModal('+full.product_id+')"` ...